# Are there any negative affects of accepting the hackers' deals?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

In Game Dev Tycoon you sometimes get messages from a team of hackers called Blowfish Studios, there messages say things like "we have recently compromised the security of a competitors computers" and Then asks you if you what to pay them to do something like sabotage there computers or steal research data.

Apart from costing money are there any negative things that can come from accepting their deals?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [wiki](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Events), there are 2 Blowfish events:

1) Industrial Spy Topic: If you accept you gain a "new game topic" and +1 Evil point. If you decline the offer, you get +1 Good and +1 Secrecy.

2) Industrial Sabotage: If you accept you gain +1 Evil. If you decline, you gain +1 Good.

Other than these listed, there seem to be no other consequences.

Comment: What happens if you get evil points?

Comment: Apparently, if you have to many evil points, a random even can happen, where your credit card gets stolen (you lose money).

Comment: Just like in real life *cough*

Comment: "Many evil points" is more than 1.  Other criteria for the "credit card stolen" event are 2+ employees and 500k money.  The event results in the loss of 7% of your money.